# Do block level elements support text-overflow: ellipsis

Tags: html, css

My text is not cutting off with an ellipsis when it overflows the div.

Usually this is very simple to accomplish, simply add the `text-overflow: ellipsis` and `overflow-x: hidden` CSS properties to text's container.

It works if you change `<p>` to `<span>`. After googling, it looks like both block and inline-block elements support text-overflow: ellipsis. Why is this happening then?

http://jsfiddle.net/p4j4326c/1/

HTML:

```
<div>
    <p>Test text that is going to overflow</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    width: 100px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: looks like it's related to the p element. Maybe this is something about block vs inline-block elements supporting ellipsis.

Comment: The title should reflect the question you are actually asking, and it should be stated clearly. Asking why “this” is happening is not a problem statement when you don’t say what “this” is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like if you modify the `p` tag it works:

```
p {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2Lmdz5ty)

Also this comes from MDN...looks like it applies for the block element:

```
"This property only affects content that is overflowing a block container 
element in its inline progression direction."
```